# What is the difference between boto3.Session().client and boto3.client?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

What is the difference between `a` and `b`?

```
>>> import boto3
>>> a = boto3.Session().client("s3")
>>> b = boto3.client("s3")
>>> a == b
False
```

Both seem to work, but for variant `a` I get the following error with `mypy`:

> Module has no attribute "Session"

This seems to be the case for all services (s3, ssm, sts, ...).

Does it maybe depend on the version if both are the same?

Comment: it's supposed to be boto3.session.Session().   Basically, ```boto3.session.Session().client("s3")``` is the same as ```boto3.client("s3")``` It's natural that a != b since you're creating two different objects.

Comment: I guessed so, but I wasn't sure :-) And it would be different with `Session()` was given some parameters, e.g. the profile. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boto3.client("s3")` creates a client using a  **default session**. Which is same as

```
boto3.DEFAULT_SESSION.client('s3')
```

`boto3.Session()`  creates new Session. Since no arguments are given, object created will be equivalent to the default session. Normally you would create new session if you want to use **new credentials profile**, e.g.

```
boto3.Session(profile_name='non-default-profile')
```

`a == b` are different since these are different instances of `Client`.

Answer (score 2):

To fix your `mypy` issue, you can try the following.

```
import boto3.session
a = boto3.session.Session().client("s3")
```

Please let me know if this helps!